# If you invest in an account that earns 4.5% interest compounded continuously..

Tags: recreational-mathematics

If you invest in an account that earns 4.5% interest compounded continuously, how long will it take to triple your money assumig you leave it in the account?

Just another fun question from a website :D

Comment: How do you know it's fun if you haven't tried answering it yourself?

Comment: I tried it myself, but couldnt work it out, using many formulas

Comment: Well what don't you share those efforts with the rest of us then?

Comment: Tried to do the A=P^ert Method, but couldnt solve using that. And i also used the A=P(1+(r/n))^nt couldnt work that out either and the growth decay method whitch is A=P(1+- r)^nt

Comment: How often is the interest added ?

Comment: I dont know @StephenG the question is all we got.

Comment: We;ll just assume "seconds" as it's Christmas !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$A = Pe^{rt}$$

You didn't specify any time unit on the rate, so I will assume it is 4.5% annual interest rate compounded continuously.

Then we have $r = 0.045$ and we are interested in solving for $t$ when $A = 3P$.

$$3P = Pe^{0.045t} \Rightarrow 3 = e^{0.045t}$$ and now take logarithm and your calculator to get the final answer.

Comment: Ok Thankyou!!!!

Comment: wait why 3P??? Where did you get that from?

Comment: P is your initial amount. So triple that would be $3P$.

Comment: Oh yeah i understand. Thankyou!